# Python - POST request repsonse and JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I´m using Python 2.7.7 to send a post request to a website. Im using the requests module and my code looks like this: (NAME and PASS are substituted)

```
r = requests.post("http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/action.php", data="act=login&name=NAME&pass=PASS&challengekeyid="+challstrarr[2]+"&challenge="+challstrarr[3])

    print(r.text)
    print(r.json())
```

r.text returns just a blank line, r.Json returns this error: "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

The website i´m requesting has the following tutorial:

> you'll need to make an HTTP POST request to http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/action.php with the data act=login&name=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&challengekeyid=KEYID&challenge=CHALLENGE
>
> Either way, the response will start with ] and be followed by a JSON object which we'll call data."

I´m not sure if the post request response is faulty (and hence the blank line) or if its not faulty and the json parsing is off

Comment: What happens when you try with curl?

Comment: I would make sure `challstrarr[2]` and `challstrarr[3]` are what you think they are and print out the data to see what it looks like

Comment: It works with curl, i get the contents of the json file, but i still get blank line with r.text.
I did check the array indizes and i did print it out, its all correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a dictionary object to the `post` function (the data argument), only in the `get` method you should pass a query string:

```
postData = {
#put you post data here
}
r = requests.post("http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/action.php", data=postData)
print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: You can check the documentation for more detail, :)